# nonblocking BIO_do_connect blocked when there is no internet connected

Tags: c, linux, ssl, openssl

I am using Openssl-0.9.8x as follows:

```
bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);
BIO_get_ssl(bio, & ssl);
SSL_set_mode(ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);
BIO_set_nbio(bio, 1);
in_addr_t serverIP =  inet_addr(HTTPS_SERVER_IP);
BIO_set_conn_ip(bio, &serverIP );
BIO_set_conn_port(bio, HTTPS_SERVER_PORT_STR);
while(1) {
    printf("BIO_do_connect start>>>>\n");
    if(BIO_do_connect(bio) <= 0 && BIO_should_retry(bio)) {
        sleep(1);
        printf("BIO_do_connect retry>>>>\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Connect success.\n");
    }
}
```

It works fine when the internet connection is OK (i.e. it can connect to the server). But, when the internet connection is limited (i.e. it can't connect to the server), the `BIO_do_connect()` is blocked after one or more times of retry.
The output as follows:

```
BIO_do_connect start>>>>
BIO_do_connect retry>>>>
BIO_do_connect start>>>>
BIO_do_connect retry>>>>
BIO_do_connect start>>>>
```

Finally, it is blocked in `BIO_do_connect(...)`? why this happened?

Comment: What is in `HTTPS_SERVER_IP`? Is it actually an IP address, or is it a hostname?

Comment: The code example above cannot be the real one since serverIP is not used at all. Only the target port is set but not the target IP or hostname. Please make a mininmal **but working** example to demonstrate your problem. Note that you are the one who needs help so you should make it easy for others to help you.

Comment: sorry, its not the real code im using, i just demostrate a simple one.     in_addr_t serverIP =  inet_addr(HTTPS_SERVER_IP);
    BIO_set_conn_ip(bio, &serverIP );
    BIO_set_conn_port(bio, HTTPS_SERVER_PORT_STR);

Comment: Have you considered breaking out of the loop on success?

Comment: @EJP - good point...

Comment: @EJP  look at my log above, it was block at "BIO_do_connect start>>>>" , no "BIO_do_connect retry>>>>" output. so its block at the BIO_do_connect(...)?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably your use of `SSL_set_mode(ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY)`.

From the 0.9.8 man page:

> SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY
>
> Never bother the application with retries if the transport is blocking.
>       If a renegotiation take place during normal operation, a
>       SSL_read() or SSL_write() would return
>       with -1 and indicate the need to retry with SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ.
>       In a non-blocking environment applications must be prepared to handle
>       incomplete read/write operations.
>       In a blocking environment, applications are not always prepared to
>       deal with read/write operations returning without success report. The
>       flag SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY will cause read/write operations to only
>       return after the handshake and successful completion.

The effect of `SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY` is to automatically retry operations that would otherwise return back to application code (even when the using blocking connections). It doesn't make any sense to use it when you *want* non-blocking operation.

Try removing that line completely.

By the way 0.9.8 is out of support and is no longer receiving security updates. You really ought to upgrade to a more recent version.

Comment: Hmmm. I just tried out your code and it "works for me" after setting up "ctx" as "ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());", and amending the code to add  a "break" after "Connect success". Running that code with no server present to connect to results in one retry followed by "Connect success" (even though it actually failed because BIO_do_connect() failed but BIO_should_retry() returned false).

Answer (score -1):

Add the following:

```
in_addr_t serverIP =  inet_addr(HTTPS_SERVER_IP);
BIO_set_conn_ip(bio, &serverIP );
BIO_set_conn_port(bio, HTTPS_SERVER_PORT_STR);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.